# Why does my code on printing Triangular Numbers not work?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My Code doesn't print out Triangular Numbers according to the formula, but only loops the number 1.

What is my mistake?

```
public class Triangular{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int t = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;

        while(n <= 10) {
            n++;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the value of `t` to somehow change in each iteration of the loop? `t` is initialized once, its value is set.

Comment: As Sotirios pointed out, order matters in programming.  Because the calculation of `t` does not occur inside the loop, it only gets calculated once.  Move the statement assigning `t` after the `while` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are increasing n by one, you are not recalculating the value of t inside the loop.

Try calculating the value of t inside the loop, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     int n = 0;
     int t = 0;
     while (n <= 10)
     {
        n++;
        t = (n * (n + 1))/2;
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}
```

Each time you increase the value of n, you need to recalculate the value of t by passing the new value of n into the formula.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is not recalculated when `n` changes. You need to assign it inside the `while` loop. Also, you may as well just do this:

```
public class Triangular {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int t = 1;

        while(n <= 10) {
            System.out.println(t);
            n++;
            t += n;
        }
    }
}
```